# customized css for sharepoint page

Tags: css, site, design

I am currently creating a webpart webpage for an user and they want it customized.

> For example : They want an `image carousel and webparts with tabs`.
>   I have figured out everything but i do no how to resize the page according to my needs.

As the image carousel looks really big and i want to apply my own resizing and everything not only to the image carousel but also to webpart zone say header, i want to reduce the header size to say 80% of width so i can fit another webpart in it.

Is this doable? 
Please respond, any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your own CSS to the webpart by following this steps :

1. Click on **Edit Page**
2. The ribbon will shows up select **Insert** tab then click on
   **Webpart**
3. Select **Media and content**
4. Select **Content Editor Webpart**
5. **Edit Webpart** then select **Edit Source**
6. Put your own CSS code with style tag

`<style type="text/css">​
     //Code here
 </style>`

7. **Stop Editing** and **Save the Page**

Or

> Instead of writing directly your code in **Edit source** i prefer that you
>   create your own css file and put on it your own code then **Link it** to
>   your Webpart.

Comment: yes i kind of know that but resizing is really hard for me and while i am inspecting the id of the element and trying to change it, it is not happening! any help with that ?

Comment: Normally it works good, just try for another element, if it still not works please share your css code here.

Comment: i tried for my header web part and for my background color but it did no work !

Answer (score 0):

Easy trick for this -

- Select the **ID of the element** that you wish to resize (use chrome or IE debugger tool, assuming that the id is "abc-xyz"
- Put in your resizing/display CSS code within your existing code appropriately. For illustration - 
      `#abc-xyz{
      width: 80% !important
      }`
- Make sure you use the ***"!important"*** i your CSS. SharePoint cosmetics behaves weird sometimes, if you skip this.